# D3 force-directed graph nodes have no attribute "weight"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am using tweaked code from http://hughsk.github.io/colony/ but I keep getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined

This stems from the force.nodes(nodes) function, for which the document says no weight needs to be set as defaults will be initialized by the layout when start() is created.

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong that keeps the weight values from being initialized?

Here is my code:

```
var colony = {
  "nodes":[
    {
      "pages":123,
      "name":"Test",
      "id":2
    },
    {
      "pages":456,
      "name":"Test2",
      "id":3
    }
  ],
  "links":[
    {
      "source":123,
      "target":456,
      "weight":100
    }
  ]
}

var nodes = colony.nodes
  , links = colony.links
  , scale = 1
  , focus

var width = 960
  , height = 960
  , link
  , node
  , text
  , textTarget = false

var colors = {
      links: 'FAFAFA'
    , text: {
        subtitle: 'FAFAFA'
    }
    , nodes: {
        method: function(d) {
            return groups[d.group].color
        }
        , hover: 'FAFAFA'
        , dep: '252929'
    }
}

links.forEach(function(link) {
    var source = function(nodes,link){
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
            if (nodes[i].id == link.source){
                return nodes[i];
            }
        }
    }
      , target = function(nodes,link){
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
            if (nodes[i].id == link.target){
                return nodes[i];
            }
        }
    }

    source.children = source.children || []
    source.children.push(link.target)

    target.parents = target.parents || []
    target.parents.push(link.source)
})

var groups = nodes.reduce(function(groups, file) {
    var group = file.mgroup || 'none'
      , index = groups.indexOf(group)

    if (index === -1) {
        index = groups.length
        groups.push(group)
    }

    file.group = index

    return groups
}, [])

groups = groups.map(function(name, n) {
    var color = d3.hsl(n / groups.length * 300, 0.7, 0.725)

    return {
          name: name
        , color: color.toString()
    };
})

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-50 * scale)
    .linkDistance(20 * scale)
    .on('tick', function() {
        link.attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; })

        node.attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })

        if (textTarget) {
            text.attr('transform'
                    , 'translate(' + textTarget.x + ',' + textTarget.y + ')')
        }
    })

var vis = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)

force.nodes(nodes)
     .links(links)
     .start()
```

Comment: The error is NOT indicating that you're missing a `weight`. Rather, it's indicating that something that should have a `weight` param is altogether undefined. I can't tell what though.

Comment: In this kind of debugging question, it would be cool to provide a jsFiddle.

Comment: @ChristopherChiche http://jsfiddle.net/xymay/    not sure if that helps, as nothing really shows up, but there it is

Comment: The console helps a lot ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you have to modify the links in the `forEach` loop, which gives you something like:

```
links.forEach(function (link) {
    //var source, target; 
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].pages == link.source) {
            link.source = nodes[i];
        }
    }


    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].pages == link.target) {
            link.target = nodes[i];
        }
    }

    link.source.children = link.source.children || []
    link.source.children.push(link.target)

    link.target.parents = link.target.parents || []
    link.target.parents.push(link.source)
    return link;
})
```

Then, in the `tick` function, you also have to iterate on all `links` and `nodes`. You can find a good example in the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-on)